# R Counting Occurences in a Column of Data Frame, Grouped by Another Column

Tags: r, dataframe

I basically have a data frame with a column of letters and a column of colors:

```
x <- data.frame(col1=c("a","b","a","c","d","d","c","a","b","c"),
                col2=c("red","orange","yellow","red","red","yellow","orange","yellow","red","orange"))

col1   col2
a      red
b      orange 
a      yellow
c      red
d      red
d      yellow
c      orange
a      yellow
b      red
c      orange
```

My goal is to create a second data frame that counts the number of occurences of each color in `col2` of `x` for each letter in `col1`.  Basically:

```
Letters   Occurences   Red   Orange  Yellow
a         3            1     0       2
b         2            1     1       0
c         3            1     2       0
d         2            1     0       1
```

Right now, I just brute forced it since there are only 3 factors of `col2`.  I used:

```
df <- data.frame(Letters = levels(factor(x$col1)))
df$Occurences <- table(x$col1)
df$red <- table(factor(x$col1[x$col2=="red"],levels=levels(factor(x$col1))))
df$orange <- table(factor(x$col1[x$col2=="orange"],levels=levels(factor(x$col1))))
df$yellow <- table(factor(x$col1[x$col2=="yellow"],levels=levels(factor(x$col1))))
```

Is there an easier way to do this, as opposed to doing each column of `df` one by one?  Especially with a data set that has a lot more than 3 factors?

Comment: `table(x)` should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pivot_wider` from tidyr

```
library(tidyr)
x %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = col2, values_from = col2, values_fn = "length", values_fill = 0)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  col1    red orange yellow
  <chr> <int>  <int>  <int>
1 a         1      0      2
2 b         1      1      0
3 c         1      2      0
4 d         1      0      1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 as.data.frame.matrix(addmargins(table(x), 2))

  orange red yellow Sum
a      0   1      2   3
b      1   1      0   2
c      2   1      0   3
d      0   1      1   2
```